# Циклический вызов при OneToOne

Tags: spring, jpa

Есть Две модели с двусторонним oneToOne но при вызове из репозитория у меня получается циклическое вызывание этих же моделей.

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "account": {
            "login": "sad",
            "password": "asdfsa",
            "machine": {
                "id": 3,
                "account": {
                    "login": "sad",
                    "password": "asdfsa",
                    "machine": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "account": {
                            "login": "sad",
                            "password": "asdfsa",
                            "machine": {
                                "id": 3,
                                "account": {
                                    "login": "sad",
                                    "password": "asdfsa",
                                    "machine": {
```

Вот сами модели

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MACHINES")
public class MachineBase implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "machine")
    private AccountBase account;

}
```

и сам аккаунт

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
public class AccountBase implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "machine_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private MachineBase machine;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В библиотеке **Jackson** *(если вы используете его для сериализации)* есть аннотации `@JsonBackReference` и `@JsonManagedReference`. Они как раз нужны для того, чтобы определить родительский и дочерний объект и избежать рекурсии при сериализации.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в трех методах, которые нам приносит аннотация `@Data`: `equals`, `hashCode` и `toString`. Кроме того, вы получите такую ошибку, если будете сериализовать объекты в `json`. Дело в том, что когда вы пытаетесь прочитать содержимое первого объекта, вам нужен второй. Но во втором есть ссылка на первый. И там мы входим в рекурсию без условия выхода из нее.

На мой взгляд, самым оптимальным решением будет настроить одностороннюю связь один к одному. Для этого нам надо продумать кто будет вызывать один объект из другого.

Comment: Да это было бы для меня решением я думал об этом, но мне нужна как раз двухстороння связь)

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите вручную equals и hashcode у обоих классов. Проблема в аннотации [@EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) и [@ToString](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString), которые включены в аннотации `@Data`.

Comment: Тогда еще надо переопределить `toString`

Comment: @faoxis, точно, забыл, спасибо)